# Change the visibility of elements in ComboBox dynamically using MVVM framework

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Ok,

I have seen a few similar questions but have not been able to figure out this problem for the past couple days.  I have two Comboboxes and I want each one to hide the selected element in the other one. For example, if I select a value in ComboBox 1 that selected item should be removed as an option in ComboBox 2.

I thought about using a command but ComboBoxes don't have commands. I have pasted below the comboboxes' XAML and ViewModel code.  I would appreciate any help with this.  I know the code below is wrong but I think that the logic for this should be in the setters of the bounded to ItemSource.

```
                <ComboBox Margin="0,7,0,0"
                          Name="ComboBoxA"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Header="{Binding AccountHeader}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ChargedAccounts,
                                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount,
                                                 Mode=TwoWay,
                                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                <ComboBox x:Uid="TargetAccountTextBox"
                          Name="ComboBoxB"
                          Margin="0,7,0,0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Header="target account"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding TargetAccounts,
                                                Mode=TwoWay,
```

```cs
namespace MoneyFox.Shared.ViewModels
{
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class ModifyPaymentViewModel : BaseViewModel, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IDefaultManager defaultManager;
        private readonly IDialogService dialogService;
    private readonly IPaymentManager paymentManager;

    //this token ensures that we will be notified when a message is sent.
    private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken token;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    // This has to be static in order to keep the value even if you leave the page to select a category.
    private double amount;
    private Payment selectedPayment;

    public ModifyPaymentViewModel(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IDialogService dialogService,
        IPaymentManager paymentManager,
        IDefaultManager defaultManager)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.dialogService = dialogService;
        this.paymentManager = paymentManager;
        this.defaultManager = defaultManager;

        TargetAccounts = unitOfWork.AccountRepository.Data;
        ChargedAccounts = unitOfWork.AccountRepository.Data;
        token = MessageHub.Subscribe<CategorySelectedMessage>(ReceiveMessage);
    }


    ObservableCollection<Account> _SelectedAccount;
    ObservableCollection<Account> SelectedAccount
    {

        get
        {
            return _SelectedAccount;
        }
        set
        {

            _SelectedAccount = value;
            for(int i = 0; i < ChargedAccounts.Count; i++)
            {
                if(ChargedAccounts[i].ToString() == _SelectedAccount.ToString())
                {
                    ChargedAccounts.Remove(ChargedAccounts[i]);
                }
            }

        }

    }

    ObservableCollection<Account> _TargetAccount;
    ObservableCollection<Account> Targetccount
    {

        get
        {
            return _SelectedAccount;
        }
        set
        {

            _SelectedAccount = value;
            for (int i = 0; i < TargetAccounts.Count; i++)
            {
                if (TargetAccounts[i].ToString() == _SelectedAccount.ToString())
                {
                    TargetAccounts.Remove(ChargedAccounts[i]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do agree with a lot of the points in the answer provided by Ed, there is a simpler way to do this without DataTriggers or Converters. There is already a filterable [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx) in the framework that is your friend (Scott Hanselman [loves it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CollectionViewSourceIsCrazyUsefulForBindingToFilteredObservableCollectionsOnWindowsPhone8.aspx))

I would bind ComboBoxA to your regular `ChargedAccounts` property, but I would modify ComboBoxB to:

- bind to a property in the code behind of the View that returns a [ICollectionView](https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/)
- in a SelectionChanged event handler for ComboBoxA (also in the code behind of the view) I would adjust the filter for the ICollectionView to exclude the currently selected item

Roughly, this can be done in just a couple of lines:

```
public ICollectionView FilteredData { get; set; }

private void ComboBoxA_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var z = new CollectionViewSource {Source = ViewModel.ChargedAccounts.Where(p => p != ViewModel.SelectedAccount) };
    FilteredData = z.View;
}
```

Of course this assumes you've done the right thing by having a ViewModel property in the code behind of your view preferably exposed as an interface, and that the `ChargedAccounts` and `SelectedAccount` properties are available via that interface.
You could also cobble these couple of lines together in your viewmodel and trigger it via a property change on `SelectedAccount` - I just have the opinion that a filter operation in response to a UI action should go in the code behind of the UI, but that decision is really up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Give the comboboxes an ItemContainerStyle (`TargetType="ComboBoxItem"`) with a data trigger. For `ComboBoxA`, that'll look like this:

```
<ComboBox
    ...
    x:Name="ComboBoxA"
    ...
    >
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding 
                            Converter="{local:ObjectEquals}"
                            >
                            <Binding 
                                Path="SelectedItem" 
                                ElementName="ComboBoxB" />
                            <!-- Binding with no properties just binds to the DataContext -->
                            <Binding />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Visibility" 
                        Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

`ComboBoxB` gets the same deal, but `ElementName="ComboBoxA"` in the `SelectedItem` binding.

And we'll need to write that multi-value converter. It's as easy as they come:

```
public class ObjectEquals : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.Length == 2 && values[0] == values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

It'd be so convenient if you could bind `DataTrigger.Value` to `{Binding}`, but it's not a dependency property.

You *could^ also do this purely in the viewmodel by temporarily removing `SelectedAccount` from `TargetAccounts` -- you'd have a private full `_targetAccountsFull` list, and a public filtered one. The setter for `SelectedAccount` would filter the list. Were you trying to do that already?

But that's not my idea of a good solution. Hiding combo box items is UI design stuff; the viewmodel shouldn't be involved in it, and in fact shouldn't even be aware that such things take place. One of the pleasures of WPF/MVVM is that you can separate that stuff out into pure UI code in the view. The viewmodel has its own complexities to worry about.

By the way, you bind `SelectedItem` to `SelectedAccount`, but `SelectedAccount` is an `ObservableCollection`. That makes no sense. There's one selected account. Make it a single `Account`, not a collection of them.